# Find contour of a sock that contains patterns

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to figure out how I can isolate a non-uniform sock on a picture.

For now I am using edge detection principally as you can see in my code :

*main :*

```
# We import the image
image = importImage(filename)
# Save the shapes variables
height, width, _ = np.shape(image)

# Get the gray scale image in a foot shape
grayImage, bigContourArea = getFootShapeImage(image, True)
minArea = width * height / 50

# Extract all contours
contours = getAllContours(grayImage)

# Keep only the contours that are not too big nor too small
relevantContours = getRelevantContours(contours, minArea, maxArea)
```

*And `getAllContours` does the following :*

```
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
# Apply Canny Edge detection algorithm
# We apply a Gaussian blur first
edges = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayIm, (5, 5), 0)
# Then we apply Edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(edges, 10, 100)
# And we do a dilatation followed by erosion to fill gaps
edges = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations=2)
edges = cv2.erode(edges, kernel, iterations=2)

_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Here are some pictures resulting from my code :

- [Original picture with foot on the drawed shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl3UO.jpg)
- [Only the biggers contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9qOj.png)
- [All contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGNct.png)

So as you can see there are some parts of the socks that are not taken in the sock contour, and I tried to include the whole sock with several techniques but never succeeded.

I tried the following :

- Segmentation using Otsu thresholding, Itti's saliency (In order to have a mask of the sock in the image and avoid all the remaining)
- Regroup the smaller contours with the big one to create an even bigger one (But then I can't avoid taking others that are outside the socks)

Do you have an idea on how i can proceed ?

Thanks in advance ! I hope it is clear enough, if you need clarifications just ask.

Comment: Will the foot always be on top of white paper and will the floor always be the same material in other images? You could do color detection to mask those out, and then combining the contours should work well. You can toss out contours that are past the sock towards the pants. If the bg will always be the same but the socks can differ, then masking out the background seems like the best way to go.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds The floor won't always be the same but I putted the white paper for that purpose, such that there is always the same color right above the foot but I don't know how to proceed in order to make use of it properly.. Thanks, I'll try some color masking algorithm and tell you how it goes !

Comment: Then you do at least know that the biggest contour that touches the paper is the foot. Similarly, you know that any smaller contours that touch the paper are also part of the foot. And you know that those smaller contours between are also the foot. This should help you connect up regions :)

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Okay I'm back, I tried to do something acceptable and it improved a lot but is not perfect yet and I wanted to know if you have an idea on how to merge contours without adding useless points ?

Comment: Just draw then onto a blank image to create a new mask.

Comment: It took me really long to do that but I finally came up to something more or less working. I am really not convinced about this technique working in all cases but at least it works here ^^ I will write a proper answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this I had to perform some color detection algorithm in order to detect the white sheet of paper that is here for this special purpose. I did so with the following :

```
# Define a mask for color I want to isolate
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lowerWhiteVals, upperWhiteVals)
# I also applied some morphological operations on the mask to make it cleaner
```

Here is the mask image obtained doing so before and after operations:

[image: Before operations] [image: After operations]

Then I detect the paper on the image by taking the left-most contour on the mask, and use it as a `left` boundary, I also split the paper contour to get a `bottom` boundary well representative.

And for the `top` and `right` I used the first sock contour I had, assuming this one will always at least have theses 2 boundaries because of how the socks are.

Once this was done I just took all the contours in my boundaries and created a new contour from that by drawing them all onto a blank image and finding the new contour again (Thanks to @Alexander Reynolds).

I also had to fine tune a bit my algorithm in order to have the more representative contour of the sock at the end and you can see what my final result is on this following image, even if it's not perfect it's more than enough for this small trial with opencv.

[image: Before] [image: After]

Thanks @Alexander for your help. And hope it will help others someday !